# CouchDB + lets encypt SSL

Tags: ssl, couchdb, lets-encrypt

Doesn't seem to find my  certificate. When I visit site with https advise if certificate is out of date and points to when the domain was first set up doesn't seem to use or find the new certificates.

Have created new lets encrypt certs in plesk (CENT OS) and even as advised copied and moved said certs to a folder in /var/lib/couchdb/certs/
gave teh folder and certs CouchDB ownership and certs also set to 600 and edited .ini as follows and restarted CouchDB but just doesn't seem to work.

```
[daemons]
; enable SSL support by uncommenting the following line and supply the PEM's below.
; the default ssl port CouchDB listens on is 6984
httpsd = {chttpd, start_link, [https]}

[ssl]
cert_file = /var/lib/couchdb/certs/fullchain.pem
key_file = /var/lib/couchdb/certs/privkey.pem
```